# WIX CNDL0001 System.EntryPointNotFoundException in Linux

Tags: wix

I trying use candle.exe in Alpine Linux with dactiv/wix docker image.

Command to test

```
docker run --rm dactiv/wix candle
```

Error message

```
latest: Pulling from dactiv/wix
86205afa28f6: Pull complete 
2ea333b253d2: Pull complete 
e446e243958c: Pull complete 
6149cd706539: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:17d232708589641f5632f9a1ff9463ad087b192cea7b8e6012d2b47ec6af5f6c
Status: Downloaded newer image for dactiv/wix:latest
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/386) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
candle.exe : error CNDL0001 : SetThreadErrorMode assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)

Exception Type: System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Stack Trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Kernel32.SetThreadErrorMode(uint,uint&)
  at System.IO.DisableMediaInsertionPrompt.Create () [0x00008] in <3d7a9349295c42b6abb3487b4473a6b8>:0
```

Answer (score 2):

WiX v3 is a .NET Framework application, so it only supports running on Windows. WiX v4 is a .NET (Core) application, so it *can* run on other platforms. However, it currently still only supports Windows because WiX depends on MSI APIs that only exist on Windows.

There have been some attempts by people to make those APIs available on non-Windowa platforms, but those experiments have not matured to a place where anyone has contributed to the WiX project.

Perhaps you'd like to do the work to support all the necessary Windows APIs on Alpine Linux and work with us in WiX to integrate the effort.